# How is possible show JSON value with different way

Tags: javascript

I wonder how it is possible in a similar situation, the solution

```
var lang_object = {
    "UK": {
        "ERROR": {
            "fullname_empty": "fullname error",
            "phone_empty": "phone error",
        } 
    }
};
```

I have JSON Object.

```
var z = 'UK';
console.log(lang_object.z.ERROR.fullname_empty);
```

this example do not work, why? z = "UK".

```
var z = eval('UK');
console.log(lang_object.z.ERROR.fullname_empty);
```

this also dont work.

```
console.log(lang_object.UK.ERROR.fullname_empty);
```

this example work

Comment: `lang_object[z].ERROR.fullname_empty`

Comment: Thank you Aioros <3

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:
`lang_object[z].ERROR.fullname_empty`

Long answer:

`object.z` refers to the value of the key `z` in the object `object`.

`object[z]` refers to the value of a key equals to the value `z`, in the object `object`.

Comment: `console.log(lang_object[z]['ERROR']['fullname_empty']);`